# Изменяется ширина страницы при переходе на другую

Tags: html, css

При переходе между страницами сайта изменяется ширина самой страницы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
 max-width: 40em;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding-left: 1em;
 padding-right: 1em;
 font-size: 1em;
}

header a {
 color: gray;
 text-decoration: none;
}

header a:hover {
 color: blue;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

article {
 font-size: 1.1875em;
 line-height: 150%;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
}

nav a {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: italic;
 display: block;
 line-height: 150%;
 color: grey;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 1.1em;
}

nav a:hover {
 color: blue;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

footer {
 text-align: center;
}

footer a {
 color: gray;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="uk">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <title>Головна</title>
</head> 

<body>
 
 <header>
  <a href=""><h1>UPS</h1></a>
 </header>

 <nav>
  <p>2019 рік</p>
  <p>Січень</p>
   <a href="article_0.html">Стаття 1</a>
   <a href="#">Стаття 1</a>
   <a href="#">Стаття 1</a>
  <p>Лютий</p>
   <a href="#">Стаття 1</a>
   <a href="#">Стаття 1</a>
  <p>2018 рік</p>
  <p>Вересень</p>
   <a href="#">Стаття 1</a>
 </nav>
<br>
 <footer>
  <p><a href="">G</a> 18</p>
 </footer>

 
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="uk">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <title>Стаття 1</title>
</head> 

<body>
 
 <header>  
  <a href="main.html"><h1>UPS</h1></a>
 </header>

 <main>
  <article>
   <h1>Стаття 1</h1>
   <p>
    Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных 
    и согласных живут рыбные тексты.<a href="#"> просто ссілка</a> Вдали от всех живут 
    они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого 
    языкового океана. Маленький ручеек Даль журчит по всей 
    стране и обеспечивает ее всеми необходимыми правилами. 
    Эта парадигматическая страна, в которой жаренные члены 
    предложения залетают прямо в рот.</p> 
    <img src="images/11.jpg" alt="photo">
    <p>Даже всемогущая 
    пунктуация не имеет власти над рыбными текстами, ведущими 
    безорфографичный образ жизни. Однажды одна маленькая 
    строчка рыбного текста по имени Lorem ipsum решила выйти 
    в большой мир грамматики. Великий Оксмокс предупреждал ее 
    о злых запятых, диких знаках вопроса и коварных точках с 
    запятой, но текст не дал сбить себя с толку. Он собрал 
    семь своих заглавных букв, подпоясал инициал за пояс и 
    пустился в дорогу.</p> 
    <img src="images/21.jpg" alt="photo">
    <p>Взобравшись на первую вершину курсивных 
    гор, бросил он последний взгляд назад, на силуэт своего 
    родного города Буквоград, на заголовок деревни Алфавит 
    и на подзаголовок своего переулка Строчка. Грустный 
    реторический вопрос скатился по его щеке и он продолжил свой 
    путь. По дороге встретил текст рукопись. Она предупредила его: 
    «В моей стране все переписывается по несколько раз. 
    Единственное, что от меня осталось, это приставка «и». 
    Возвращайся ты лучше в свою безопасную страну». Не послушавшись 
    рукописи, наш текст продолжил свой путь. Вскоре ему 
    повстречался коварный составитель  
   </p>
  </article> 
 </main>
<br>
 <nav> <p>Почитать еще:</p>
  <p>2019 рік</p>
  <p>Січень</p>
   <a href="#">Стаття 1</a>
   <a href="#">Стаття 1</a>
   <a href="#">Стаття 1</a>
  <p>Лютий</p>
   <a href="#">Стаття 1</a>
   <a href="#">Стаття 1</a>
  <p>2018 рік</p>
  <p>Вересень</p>
   <a href="#">Стаття 1</a>
 </nav>
<br>
 <footer>
  <p><a href="">G</a> 18</p>
 </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

И такой сдвиг во всех браузерах. Как исправить?

Comment: FF 62 и Chrome 67 - ширина страницы 640px

Если вас смущает сдвиг - это полоса прокрутки. Из за нее центрирование смещается.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Вопрос из-за невнимательности.

Answer (score 0):

Как отметил @UserTest01, проблема в полосе прокрутки.

На первой картинке много контента и полоса прокрутки справа забирает на себя часть пространства, а на второй картинке контента мало и полосы прокрутки нет. Данную проблему можно решить при помоши js, добавляя в нужный момент отступ справа или через css задать отображение полосы прокрутки всегда, даже при малом количестве контента: `overflow-y: scroll;`